# spring-data-commons-2.0.0: No property delete found for type T! ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-webflux

**Issue**: *While trying spring web reactive along with spring data by  extending ReactiveCrudRepository. I am getting following error* :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property delete found for type Product!
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$new$0(PropertyPath.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:82) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:304) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:284) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:239) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:240) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:368) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:369) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:92) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:67) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:214) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$null$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:410) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$2(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:412) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:403) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

Code:

**Product** :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT")
public class Product implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
    private Long productId;

    @Column(name="PRODUCT_NAME")
    private String productName;



}
```

**Product Repository** :

```
public interface ProductRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Product, Long>{
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Github: [Project Link](https://github.com/BarathArivazhagan/Spring-Reactor-workshop/tree/master/spring-reactive-mvc-tomcat)

please suggest what is the issue here and how to resolve it.

Comment: Similar issue : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/issues/241

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni hey thanks for the quick response. As the issue hasnt fixed and rerouted to stackoverflow. Let us try to get the response from the concerned team.

Comment: Thanks for the github link. Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error occurs because `ReactiveCrudRepository` is not supported by [Spring Data JPA](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/).

According to this [Spring Data official blog bost (November 23, 2016)](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/23/first-milestone-of-next-generation-spring-data-released), only MongoDB, Cassandra and Redis are supported for now:

> **Support for reactive data access**
>
> The most significant additions that made it into the milestone is the addition of support for reactive data access for selected stores. This means: reactive Spring Data repositories and templates for **MongoDB, Cassandra and Redis**.

According to a comment by Mark Paluch on [jira.spring.io](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-701) JPA will not be supported.

> **We won't provide reactive support for Spring Data JPA.** Exposing a reactive API creates the expectation of being reactive but that's the exact opposite for JPA. JPA is blocking, requires a transaction context, that is bound to a thread and the whole JDBC backend follows a blocking approach as well. Providing a reactive API for relational databases could still make sense in a context of reactive/asynchronous database drivers.

Here is another related StackOverflow question : [ReactiveCrudRepository to use Hibernate in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483194/reactivecrudrepository-to-use-hibernate-in-spring).