# It's possible to integrate reactive Spring Data with mysql?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, reactive-programming

In the past, I integrated reactive spring data with mongoDb and everything gone fine.
Now I want the same non blocking access using mysql, but i didnt find any article about it.
I wish to use a mature and standard spring library, if you know one, please share it to me.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483194/reactivecrudrepository-to-use-hibernate-in-spring) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is R2DBC and Spring Data R2DBC.

[R2DBC](https://r2dbc.io/) is a reactive alternative to JDBC.
And [Spring Data R2DBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc) is a Spring Data module for it.

Since R2DBC is only a specification/API you also need a driver for the database of your choice. For MySql that would be https://github.com/jasync-sql/jasync-sql

Comment: R2DBC is GA now

Comment: @oshai Thanks for noting. I removed that section of the answer.